# Convert .whl file to other platform

Tags: python, android, python-wheel

I want python library in whl file that run in Android arm64-v8a. But on PyPI, there are only for Window, Linux and Mac platform. I saw people using the wheel library so I test it using Numpy. I download zip file source code from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files) and run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` on Linux. I saw from web that the result should be `-any`, which can be run in any platform. However, the result whl file only run on Linux platform. I also tried on Window and `-win_amd64` file is produced. How can I have a whl file that is compatible in any platform or specifically Android? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+numpy

Comment: @phd Thanks for your reply. I am not looking for numpy whl android file. I am just testing for convertion using numpy... The real library I want is cvxpy whl in Android arm64-v8a.

Answer (score 0):

Linux and Windows .whl files contain native code, so they cannot be converted to another platform. To build a .whl for Android, the easiest way is to use [this build tool](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/tree/master/server/pypi).